# Apache Server: no listening sockets available

Tags: apache, tomcat, port

I recently downloaded an Apache server binary (Apache 2.4.12 x64)

When I try to run the server in command prompt I get the following error:

> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>
> AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
>
> AH00015: Unable to open logs

I'm guessing that port 80 is already being used. How do I change the binding port, which port(s) should I use? If there is another problem how do I solve it?

Comment: In my case, I was trying to start the apache server while I had NGINX server already running and listening to the port 80. So I did `service nginx stop` and then `service apache2 start`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check these:

- Check if port 80 is being used by any other process – “netstat -o
- Shut down IIS from the commadn line: “net stop was /y”

Shutting Skype works for me as it is using port 8080

Try to edit httpd file in conf folder and edit the following entry-change Listen port **from `Listen 80`
 to

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8080
```

Comment: `net stop was /y` doesn't work anymore on windows 10. Here you see how to shut down IIS in order to avoid this problem:
https://superuser.com/questions/1377068/how-do-i-disable-the-iis-server-on-windows-10-and-free-up-port-80

Comment: In my case, it's because I didn't have the Listen directive to begin with.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

In my case I can see:

**tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2604/docker-proxy**

I can then kill that process:

`kill 2604`

And then successfully restart Apache.

Answer (score 4):

In httpd.conf there should be an entry like "Listen 80". Sometimes default port 80 is taken by some other application (I remember that Skype used to use that port for example). Other more or less standard ports to use are 8000 and 8080, but generally you can set it to whatever you want, if you are just playing locally. More info can be obtained in the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html).